# unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 9-10

Tags: python, unicode

I Have below python code with simple assignements.

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
failed_script_name="Z:\Python\FAILED_CODE"+str(date.today())+".txt"
fail_script_name="Z:\Python\FAIL_CODE"+str(date.today())+".txt"
need_script_name="Z:\Python\NEED_CODE_"+str(date.today())+".txt"
```

and I am getting error in third assignment. If i comment the third assignment its working. I don't get whats wrong with third assignment as it is same as the first two

```
File "Z:\Python\test.py", line 5
    need_script_name="Z:\Python\NEED_CODE_"+str(date.today())+".txt"
                ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in 
position 9-10: malformed \N character escape
```

Comment: You should escape backslashes in string literals. Or use a raw string literal.

Comment: but why first and second assignments are working without escape backslashes

Comment: Because `"\P"` and `"\F"` are not recognised escape code sequences, and hence are ignored. [This document](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) explains the meaning of `"\N"`, which starts a named Unicode reference. It's malformed because it should be followed by a name in braces.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash `\` is used as an escape character in Python string literals. An escape character is used to represent characters, which can not be typed directly into the source code.

If the `\` is encountered in a string literal, python will determine what to do by looking at the next character. For example `N` indicates to Python, that the following brace-enclosed sequence of characters should be read as the name of a Unicode character, which will then inserted at that point, e.g.

```
>>> print("\N{RIGHTWARDS ARROW}")
→
```

However in your case you follow `\N` by something else which cannot be interpreted that way. Therefore the error message.

In the case of `P` and `F` after `\`, these are assigned no special meaning in Python and by design Python will in such cases leave both the `\` and the following character unchanged in the string literal. Therefore these don't generate an error or any problem for you:

```
>>> print("\P\F")
\P\F
```

One can properly insert a `\` in a string literal by following it with another `\`, which indicates to Python that you want to have a single backslash in the string literal:

```
>>> print("\\N{RIGHTWARDS ARROW}")
\N{RIGHTWARDS ARROW}
```

Alternatively you can turn off the special meaning of `\`, by prefixing the string literal with a `r`, making it a *raw string literal*:

```
>>> print(r"\N{RIGHTWARDS ARROW}")
\N{RIGHTWARDS ARROW}
```

[Also see the Python documentation which has a list of escape sequences and their interpretation.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

The answer above assumes Python 3.x. In Python 2.x `\N` would not be assigned any special meaning in a usual string, i.e. `"\Nonesense"` would only generate an error if it was prefixed by `u` to make it a unicode string literal `u"\Nonesense"`, for which the escape sequence also applies in Python 2.

[See also Python 2.x documentation.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string)